# DynamoDB Mapper "batchLoad()" input

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I was just using batchLoad function of dynamoDB. Here, the [documentation](http://javadox.com/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.3.27/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#batchLoad(java.util.Map)) 
of the function says, the input it takes is `List<KeyPair>`. But when I use a KeyPair object, it throws the error that the argument should be a `dynamodb annotated class`.

I can use a DynamoDB class, where I set only `hashKey and rangeKey` attributes of the class and pass them as an argument. But now my use case is the Class(DynamoDB annotated), I am using has `@NonNull` fields. If I have to pass arguments for this I have to set junk values in them, which is obviously not desirable. Any kind of help/ suggestions ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a working example:

**Summary:**

- Model class - This should be the key of the map.
- keyPairList - This is a list of key pairs that you would like to retrieve.

**With model class:**

```java
Map<Class<?>, List<KeyPair>> keyPairForTable = new HashMap<>();
                keyPairForTable.put(Movies.class, keyPairList);
```

**Full code:**

```java
public Boolean batchLoadMoviesUsingKeyPair() {

    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);

    KeyPair keyPair1 = new KeyPair();
    keyPair1.withHashKey(1991);
    keyPair1.withRangeKey("Movie with map attribute");
    
    KeyPair keyPair2 = new KeyPair();
    keyPair2.withHashKey(2010);
    keyPair2.withRangeKey("The Big New Movie 2010");

    List<KeyPair> keyPairList = new ArrayList<>();
    keyPairList.add(keyPair1);
    keyPairList.add(keyPair2);

    Map<Class<?>, List<KeyPair>> keyPairForTable = new HashMap<>();
    keyPairForTable.put(Movies.class, keyPairList);

    Map<String, List<Object>> batchResults = dynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(keyPairForTable);

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : batchResults.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had already figured out, my bad, I was using `public 
 Map<String,List<Object>> batchLoad(Iterable<? extends Object> itemsToGet, DynamoDBMapperConfig config)`. But will accept, since you helped and obviously it is the correct approach!

Comment: Good and Thanks!

Comment: I had a small doubt here. If my table does not have a range key, do we set the `rangekey` to null in `KeyPair` or do we not set it at all ?

Comment: you don't set it at all. either ways it will be null